# NetPlan Static IP address not acceptiing

Tags: server, 17.10, ip, netplan

Trying to setup Static IP and it will not work.

IP address 192.168.100.40

pre 17.10 and netplan config as follows

```
auto ens160
iface ens160 inet static
address 192.168.100.45
netmask 255.255.252.0
network 192.168.100.0
broadcst 192.168.103.255
gateway 192.168.100.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.100.1
```

Run `sudo netplan ifupdown-migrate`

And get `ens160: method static is not supported`

Try to use this netplan config and it errors out

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
        dhcp4: no
            addresses: [192.168.100.40/22]
            gateway4: 192.168.100.1
            nameservers:
            addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

add `dhhcp6: yes` and still errors out via netplan debug

What am I missing?

Comment: “still errors out...” What is the exact error? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

Please try:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: yes
      addresses: [192.168.100.40/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.100.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

In other words, /24 instead of /22 and correct the spacing and indentation. Follow with:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Please post any warnings or errors.

Comment: /22 was actually correct in their example. The issue is only indentation.

Comment: I believe /24, implying the usual 255.255.255.0, is correct.

Comment: It certainly doesn't match the config in the question: netmask 255.255.252.0

Comment: Hi Chilli555 Tried your action plan still not working get this error Invalid YAML at //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 8 column 21: mapping values are not allowed in this context which is exactly the same error as with /22 which is valid in my config

Comment: Please proofread carefully. Carefully check the spacing and indentation. Confirm there are no typos, such as *adresses*. Please confirm that the selected address, xx.40, is outside the DHCP pool in the router. Are you saying that /22 works in netplan but /24 does not? Finally, please run and post: `netplan --debug generate`

Comment: Thanks Chilli issue was the indent for the Addresses for the DNS after fixing this it worked

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour Glad it's working.

Comment: sad things is, I need to reboot to enable it, or make it works to networkd. even restarting systemd-networkd not working, at least rebooting works.